# shell script to check the sybase iq status

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sybase

I am writing a script to check whether sybase is running on my server. If it is not running, i want to start the service. If it is running, i want to stop the sybase iq.
Please help me doing the same.

The logic i have written is :

```
 if(sybaseiq = active)
   then 
    stop_iq

 else 
    start_iq ".cfg" ".db"
```

Below is the code which I found on internet.But i am not able to understand what they are doing there. Please answer me with explanation.

```
  isql -U${USERNAME} -P${PASSWORD} -S${SQL_SERVER} -w1000 << ! > ${LOG_FILE}
     exit
     !
   if [[ $? != 0 ]]
   then
       msg="`date` ${SQL_SERVER} problem. ${SQL_SERVER} on ${HOST} is down or cannot be accessed"
   cat ${LOG_FILE}|/usr/bin/mailx -s "${msg}" ${SUPPORT}
   }
   exit 1
   fi
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1):

The script is fairly straight forward

First the script logs into the server via isql, redirecting the output to a log file.  If it's able to connect, it issues all the commands between the exclamation points, which is an `exit` in this case.

Next the if statement checks the error status of the last command run `$?`.  0 indicates no error, anything else indicates an error.  So if the error is not 0, then create a message, then send that message, along with the log file to someone.

You will have to set the values for `$USERNAME, $PASSWORD, $SQL_SERVER, $LOG_FILE, $HOST and $SUPPORT` somewhere in your script.

If you are not familiar with shell scripts, I would recommend you read up a bit.  It's quite easy to get into, but they are quite powerful for managing *nix systems.